# Getting intellisense for properties from an abstract class

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a function that returns an abstract class (not adding types here, and currently have "any" for the `thing` property).

*BaseClass.ts*

```js
export function BaseClass(cls) {

  const thing = someFunction(cls)
    
  abstract class BaseThingClass{
    public model
    constructor() {
      this.thing = thing
    }
    // ....other code
  } 
  return BaseThingClass
}
```

And I extend the abstract class:

*FinalClass.ts*

```
export class FinalClass extends BaseClass(SomeClass){

  async someFunction() {
    const stuff = await this.thing.someFunction()
    return stuff
  }
}
```

This code works overall, but in VSCode, I was expecting to get intellisense to see the properties of `this.thing` in `FanalClass`. Is it because `thing` is of type `any` currently? Is getting intellisense on abstract class properties possible?

Scott

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a generic type parameter to the `BaseClass` function in order to capture the actual type passed into the function when you use it in `extends`:

```
export function BaseClass<T>(cls: new ()=> T) {

  const thing = new cls()
    
  return class BaseThingClass{
    public thing:T
    constructor() {
      this.thing = thing
    }
  } 
}


export class FinalClass extends BaseClass(SomeClass){

  async someFunction() {
    const stuff = await this.thing.someFunction()
    return stuff
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitReturns=false&ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=4&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GUIFtgDCqGcA3gFBxVzoCeAdgnGnsAGICujMAlhPQAoAlGQC+5ceVCRYcAGZcEvfnABC6QsTQAeACoA+AcjQAuOPWAB3OMIC8+uLpEVKifmngwAFj3oBzOFtzK0QkNGFXKlcoYBgOKHpQ9Ex1NGBdH38iZIpqODAOACMkHiZvXz8TXUi3eg8oDiVoYTIaqnK0ADpy-0C4Hr8a8SpROAlyCeloeGRkuDZfFCRsklAYYHoAExSNFfCcfD2hFyo6RmZWTm4+QWcahHd4Dw45OT6USxQeTx8ugc6WPgrkobhE8jE4glmHFXq5xKIgA)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only thing with "thing" is, I have a function altering it. See my example please. Let's say I know what the type of "thing" should be. Can I set the type of the thing property of the BaseThingClass? I tried it, but that didn't seem to work either.